# PLEASE HELP How can write circular category selection page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

[imgae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VcYQ.png)

I wanna do a app just like that. But I dont know how can I do this category selection panel. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use stack as parent widget and then place these circular objects(container widgets) in the children's tag of stack widget and each child(circle) must be having a positioned widget as parent.

Comment: but is it responsive when done that way? Or is it a professional code? For example, when I want to add a new category, do I have to do it manually?

Comment: you can obviously make it responsive and moreover it is upto you if you want to add each circle manually or not because you can design an algorithm to make it responsive and dynamic in size as well, in that case you may want to remove the stack widget and need to use wrap for that purpose, you can find about wrap widget here - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html